# Can not access any site with Chrome but Chromium does access any site well at the same time

Tags: macos, networking, google-chrome, security, https

I'm in for trouble with Chrome on my Mac after I backed to my home. The problem is I can not access the site such https://www.google.com with error code "ERR_ACCESS_DENIED". Even It's not restricted by Symantec but it popped up like it's restricted by Symantec application firewall. Before 5 mins I could use Chrome via Wi-Fi of 4G at Cafe also before I went to cafe I could access any site with Chrome. 
So, I tried to ping to www.google.com, telnet to 443 port of the site. It worked fine. Also I can use Chromium to access the site without any problem. I really assume somebody is attacked me when I use Chrome to access Internet. Because, When I reboot Chrome the PID was changed and it worked for a second but after few seconds It could not access to the site with error code "ERR_ACCESS_DENIED" immediately. Could you tell me where I should check about Mac with Chrome to access internet. I really assume the issue is man in the middle attack or another attack method.Could you help me?

**Problem:**

Can not access any site such www.google.com with Chrome and the error message is ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.

**My question:**

- How I can identify this issue with Chrome? or How can I chrome work fine? How I can identify this is generated by Chrome when to access internet?
- Why is default firewall of Mac enabled even I have enabled Symantec firewall?
- Is there a method to erase signals on bus of Mac by microwave or something?

**Verification:**

- OK to ping www.google.com
- OK to telnet www.google.com 443
- OK to browse any site with Chromium
- OK to assign "allow" to run "Google Chrome.app" on Symantec.
- NG to browse any site with Chrome
- OK to run function to verify the version is latest of Chrome
- (NG to access any site with Chrome after Uninstalled Symantec and reinstalled Chrome. I had same problem just 2 weeks ago.)
- No HTTPS/HTTP request from Chrome but DNS request is appeared in the console of Wireshark at the same time when I clicked refresh button. But after 4 hours it worked fine without changing any configuration.

**Out of scope:**

- Rebuilding my Mac
- Reinstalling Chrome

**My environment:**

- OS X Mavericks 10.9.2
- Chrome 33.0.1750.146
- Symantec Internet Security (Application firewall is properly configured)

**In addition:**

No change my setting, not new updates installed and no reboot today

Now, I'm going to investigate this issue by myself but I would like to have your knowledge to identify the issue as soon as possible. Please kindly advice me.

Comment: Why is reinstalling Chrome "out of scope"?  Does it behave any differently if you fully disable (and/or temporarily uninstall) the Symantec suite?

Comment: @techie007 I had like this problem 2 weeks ago. So, I uninstalled Symantec and reinstalled Chrome without installing Symantec. But, It did not fix. After few hours It worked. So, I really doubt the packet is replaced by someone.I updated my question about it now. I will check packet.